# Why does this evaluate to true?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does (0 == ‘Hello’) return true in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894350/why-does-0-hello-return-true-in-php)

```
<?php
echo ('names' == 0) ? 1 :0;
?>
```

Evaluates to TRUE

If I add an extra equals sign it will work, but this is counter intuitive.

```
<?php
echo ('names' === 0) ? 1 :0;
?>
```

Evaluates to FALSE

```
<?php
echo ('names' == FALSE) ? 1 :0;
?>
```

Evaluates to FALSE

Also found this:
[Why does 1234 == '1234 test' evaluate to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151997/why-does-1234-1234-test-evaluate-to-true?rq=1)

Comment: Reported as a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44999), explained in link there, in line with @Ynhockey's answer.

Comment: Grant could you be any less constructive?

Comment: Did you check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: Question has been answered. But thanks.

Comment: Vote to close duplicate please.

Comment: PHP likes numbers, so when comparing a string with a number, it tries to convert the string to a number. This is why `'1aab' == 1` is true, and it's the same reason why your expression is true.

Comment: Because it has no numbers at all? wow.. this is why i hate loosely typed languages

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the numerical value of the string 'names' is 0, but the boolean value is `true` (as far as I know, any non-empty string that's not also '0' or something similar is equivalent to `true` in PHP).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151997/why-does-1234-1234-test-evaluate-to-true?rq=1